# Jquery.change firing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="AddList" class="locType">Select a location</label>
<select id="AddList">
     <option value="New">New Address...</option>
</select>
```

The Js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Location Code
    $("#AddList").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $("#AddList option:selected").each(function() {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        alert(str);            
    })
    .change();
});
```

I'm trying to alert the contents whenever the user selects an option in the combobox.
Also, could the code be provided to get the value of the selected option also.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `.change();` yourself right after you bind it:

```
//Location Code
$("#AddList").change(function() {
    /* your logic */           
})
.change(); // right here you're calling it
```

Getting the value of the option:

```
$("#AddList option:selected").each(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By writing `.change();` at the end of your code, you are manually firing the `change` event.

What were you trying to do?

---

To get the value of the `option` element, call the `val` method.